# Como mostrar fecha en formato yyyy/mm/dd en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando un sistema web y colocando una fecha actual en forma de widget que se muestre cada vez que se ejecute la ventana lo he hecho en javascript si funciona me muestra de la siguiente manera 6/2/2021, lo que quiero es agregarle los ceros quedando de esta forma 06/02/2021.

Este es el código:

```
    function fecha_atual() {
  
var fecha = new Date();

  var mes = fecha.getUTCMonth() + 1;

  var dia = fecha.getUTCDate();

  var año = fecha.getUTCFullYear();

  document.getElementById("fecha").innerHTML = dia + "/" + mes + "/" + año;

}

fecha_atual();

setInterval(fecha_atual, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar el cero con un operador condicional así:

```
var mes = (fecha.getUTCMonth()<=10?'0':'')+(fecha.getUTCMonth()+1);
var dia = (fecha.getUTCDate()<10?'0':'')+fecha.getUTCDate();
```